# How can I email error logs from AWS Spark

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a process that uses AWS EMR to run a pyspark cluster.

I have a S3 location where all the process logs gets stored.

I want to understand that is there a way I can filter out ERROR logs and get them mailed to my inbox. I do not want to save any log file on my system.

Is there any python library which can help me monitor real time logs. I have seen the boto3 and EMR library, but I could not find a answer to my problem from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EMR logs will likely be buffered up into chunks of a few minutes or some size before being written to S3 ( but full disclosure, that's based on experience with other AWS S3 logging systems, not EMR itself).

If I were attempting to solve this problem, I'd use an AWS Lambda function to execute python that would read the S3 logs line by line and filter for the lines matching `ERROR`, and then use SNS to send the logs to your email address.  You can use S3 events to automatically trigger the Lambda when objects are written to the S3 logging location for EMR, so this is as close to realtime as you're gonna get.

The architecture I am suggesting looks something like this

`EMR -> S3 -> Lambda -> SNS -> email inbox`

The write of each EMR log to s3 [triggers a lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) which uses boto3
to filter the log for error messages, sending alerts to an SNS topic for distribution to users.

It may seem like a lot of moving parts but it won't require much to maintain it and should cost you only a few cents a month more than the S3 storage is already costing you.  And the effort for the whole thing is actually pretty small.

Furthermore, you won't need:

- a place to execute your code, servers to manage, etc
- nontrivial deployment model for your project
- any parts not shown above, for that matter

And you'll get for free:

- Monitoring in the form of

  - cloudwatch metrics for lambda,
  - s3 logs (should you enable them)
  - cloudwatch logs that store your function's execution windows and stdout.
- Easy integration into alerting through cloudwatch Alarms ( these typically  integrate well with Pager Duty and the like )
- dead-simple exensibility, such as

  - SNS can send SMS messages to your phone
  - add more parsing options in the lambda and redeploy
  - expose cloudwatch metrics and add alarms for thresholds
  - write the summary to S3 for pre signed email or sms links, or further processing now or later

You could send the email yourself through SES or just manually with python, but I would rather use SNS so that the subscriptions to the topic can vary independently from the python code.

Lambdas are a little intimidating to start with, but they'll include the boto3 sdk by default (which should obviate the need for a zipfile with pip dependencies all together ), which will simplify creation.

For that matter, you can set all this stuff up in the AWS console if you like doing things by dragging mouse pointers around, or intend to do it only a few times, or you can express all if it in cloudformation if you need something repeatable.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: I was wondering as to how should I initiate Lamba since each time my code will create a new cluster with a new name. How should I trigger code initially  to locate where the log is on AWS?

Comment: You could create the lambda along with the emr.  Are your codes controlling anything on the s3 logging side?  Bucket name?  You could pick up all events for that bucket.  Or, your automation for creating the emr could also create the s3 event for an existing lambda

Comment: Looks like you can use the 'DescribeCluster' api call to expose the log uri of the emr cluster in question after it's created, too: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_DescribeCluster.html

Comment: I have limited knowledge of lambda but from what I have herd, it can only be used for codes which run less than equal to 5 mins or so.If not then lambda seems a good option.

Comment: Do you really expect it to take anywhere near 5 minutes to pull an S3 file line by line, apply a regex to each, and send an email?  It would be invoked for each log file uploaded to S3.  This is how we queue CloudTrail logs for ingestion into LogStash at my workplace

Comment: Ohh damm. Got confused. We were triggering it.This is a good suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've tried to update the answer to be more clear ( though I got a little carried away, but hopefully it makes a better case now)